# Copy multiple shapes from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an analog situation to the previous one defined here:

[VBA Excel - copy from multiple various ranges at once and paste in different cell ranges of newly created workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151538/vba-excel-copy-from-multiple-various-ranges-at-once-and-paste-in-different-cel)

where I would like to paste several shapes into the newly created workbook

I tried this solution:

[excel Copy shapes from one worksheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950757/excel-copy-shapes-from-one-worksheet-to-another)

which led me to the following code:

```
 Sub Generator1()
 Dim wkd As Workbook, mwkt As Workbook
 Dim ms As Worksheet, tw As Worksheet

 Dim nashp As Shape, vmo2shp As Shape, sishp As Shape

 Set mwkt = ThisWorkbook
 Set tw = mwkt.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1")

 Set nashp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes("NorthArrow")
 Set vmo2shp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes("Vi2")
 Set siishp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes("Si23")
nashp.Copy
vmo2shp.Copy
siishp.Copy

 Set wkd = Workbooks.Add

 With wkd
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'SaveAs.Filename:="test"
 Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "1"
.Sheets("1").HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("1").Rows(42)
.Sheets("1").VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("1").Columns(13)
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Set ms = .Sheets("1")
'PROVIDING DATA FROM MAJOR ASBUILT DOCUMENT
 ms.Range("F36").Value = tw.Range("F121").Value
 ms.Range("F37").Value = tw.Range("F122").Value
 ms.Range("F38").Value = tw.Range("F123").Value
 ms.Range("F39").Value = tw.Range("F124").Value
 ms.Range("F39").Value = tw.Range("F124").Value
 ms.Range("AF1").Value = tw.Range("E131").Value
```

This method doesn't work at all.

Is there a chance to copy all the shapes to the newly created workbook?

Comment: OK thank you. Unfortunately, this approach didn't solve my problem. In fact, it works, but the way of copying wasn't right. I've changed my question slightly. Are you able to help me with this one?

Comment: Does the placement of the copied shape on the new sheet have to be the same as on the original sheet? Are all the shapes to be copied from one sheet only in the original workbook?

Comment: Yes, that would be beneficial to have them in the same place. Yes, all of them are from the same worksheet belonging to "old" workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's likely several approaches. Here's one using an array of shape names:

Remove

```
Dim nashp As Shape, vmo2shp As Shape, sishp As Shape

Set nashp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes("NorthArrow")
Set vmo2shp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes("Vi2")
Set siishp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes("Si23")

nashp.Copy
vmo2shp.Copy
siishp.Copy
```

then after the creation of the new workbook:

```
Set ms = .Sheets("1")

Dim shapeNames As Variant
shapeNames = Array("NorthArrow", "Vi2", "Si23")

Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(shapeNames) to Ubound(shapeNames)
     Dim shp As Shape
     Set shp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Build Complete Photos1").Shapes(shapeNames(i))

     shp.Copy
     ms.Paste
     ms.Shapes(ms.Shapes.Count).Top = shp.Top
     ms.Shapes(ms.Shapes.Count).Left = shp.Left
Next
```